# Why is my vertical scrollbar not correctly visible by the height of the header div

Tags: html, css

If you look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bastien/PybrF/1/

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#content {       
    top: 51px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

If you resize the window then the vertical scrollbar gets visible in the content div. BUT it gets only visible (so it seems for me...) when I have exceeded the height in pixel of the header while resizing the window.

How can I get the vertical scrollbar correctly?

**UPDATE**

I want a header which stays fixed.
I want a content which has inside scrollbars.

something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bastien/PybrF/7/

but the vertical scrollbars should start inside the content div and not start at the header/body.

Comment: Because you're using fixed positioning.

Comment: Regarding your UDPATE fiddle: The scrollbar appears to already be working the way you describe. "...scrollbars should start inside the content div..." Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Due to your use of fixed positioning and application of overflow settings, only the `#content` area will scroll.

Consider this:

1) Add the orange background color to the `body` element and remove its margins:

```css
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color: orange;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

2)  Position the other elements relatively:

```css
#header {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#container {
    position:relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PybrF/6/

---

EDIT:

I'm still unclear on what you're looking for, but here's another method.
This one keeps the header fixed and puts the scrollbar inside the `#content` area.

```css
body {
    background-color: orange;
    margin:0px;
}
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index:1; /* keep the header on top of the content */
}
#content {
    position:relative;
    padding-top:50px; /* height of the header */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PybrF/8/

Comment: I do not want this behavior of scrolling the whole body/site. I want that that the header stays fixed without scrollbars and only the content shall scroll.

Comment: Oh, okay. Isn't that what you already had? I must be misunderstanding.

Comment: I edited my initial question please read for further information!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#header, #content { width: 100%; position: absolute; }

#header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#content {
    top: 50px;
    height: 70%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Will produce this:

[image]

As for the height of the content to use all the space left, **I** would to a js function wired to the resize event to set the height of the content to the page height minus the height of the header. I honestly don't know another solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

ok I knew it must work:

Still found some old similar code and refactored it:

have fun! :)

```
Sorry for telling crap.
```

Remove the width/height percentage settings and use the left/right/bottom etc settings. Thats enough.

Forget about the main div which was from this other project long ago.

http://jsfiddle.net/bastien/PybrF/12/

Comment: I don't see a difference between this and your original fiddle. In fact, the original fiddle seems to work better. Can you explain how this one fixed your problem? Thanks!

Comment: This fiddle has different code. There is a wrapper div called main. Look at the different behavior when the scrollbars starts to show. The original fiddle scrollbar behavior is broken because the scollbar shows too late by the height of the header.

Comment: Ohhh, I see what you mean. The text overflows `#content` by the height of the header before the scrollbar appears. Thanks for clarifying :)